# How to suppress the creation of .bash_history in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'd like to suppress the *creation* of `.bash_history` in Bash. Is this at all possible?

Note that I am aware of `export HISTSIZE=0`, but that still leaves an empty `.bash_history` sitting around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> HISTFILE
>
> The name of the file in which command history is saved (see HISTORY below).  The default value is ~/.bash_history.  If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.

So you could either run

```
unset HISTFILE
```

or

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. No idea how I missed this one, but I did.